# Freeze issue when using Parallel.ForEach

Tags: c#, export-to-excel, parallel.foreach

I'm using Parallel.ForEach as the sample:

```
ParallelOptions parallelOpt = new ParallelOptions();
parallelOpt.MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 2;
Parallel.ForEach(list, parallelOpt, info =>
    {
        int threadID = Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId;
        //use tmp var to avoid conflic with original var when using thread
        ML_Scheduler tmp = new ML_Scheduler();
        tmp = ObjectCopier.Clone<ML_Scheduler>(info);
        Stopwatch sw1 = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        logger.Info("\r\n\r\n");
        logger.Info(string.Format("[{0}]****** Begin to schedule work with ThreadID {0} for ScheduleID {1}.", threadID, tmp.SchedulerID));
        WorkWithEachSchedule(threadID, tmp, tmp.SchedulerID, dtNow, tmp.StartTime, false);
        TimeSpan time1 = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(sw1.ElapsedMilliseconds / 1000.0);
        logger.Info(string.Format("[{0}]****** Finish to work with ThreadID {0} (during time : {1}).", threadID, time1.ToString(@"hh\:mm\:ss\:fff")));
    }
);
```

In function WorkWithEachSchedule, I just do:

1. Create datatable with around 10000 records for testing.
2. Export datatable to excel 2007
3. Save to local folder.

In the beginning, when I check Task Manager in Details, I see that the CPU and Memory is working.

But after some minutes, the program will freeze (as the sample image)
[image]

Both of CPU and Memory do not work, the program does not work anything more.

And I also cannot debug by breakpoint.

**Update:**

In my code, I use function ExporttoExcel as following link: http://mikesknowledgebase.azurewebsites.net/pages/CSharp/ExportToExcel.htm

And when I remove this function, the program can works correct.

I don't know why that function causes the issue.

Any advice. Thanks.

Comment: how do you export to excel?

Comment: What happens with 1 MaxDOP?

Comment: You can always pause the program and then go through threads/tasks, and on each one examine its stack. Very likely you can find in this way some shared method, that is used concurrently but was not designed as concurrently safe or you can find a reason for deadlock. For any further help, you will have to provide code that is hidden to us. It is ok to cook from water, but still, you need some ingredients too:).

Comment: Usualy you can not debug stuff, that is outside scope of your projects code, that is third party libraries, code related to system calls etc. Also creating 10k records, well let's say, that it could be slow in excel, but that is all about missing info. Does it work ok running only sequentially?

Comment: @spender, with 1 MaxDOP, it works correct. Process one by one schedule.

Comment: @Backs, I used a func as following link http://mikesknowledgebase.azurewebsites.net/pages/CSharp/ExportToExcel.htm

Comment: @ipavlu, yes, it work ok when running only sequentially (with 1 MaxDOP)

Comment: If you cant debug with break point try to comment codes inside foreach line by line until you find out which line is causing problem. You may need to use lock in some cases.

Comment: I had the same problem with OpenXML, check here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21482820/openxml-hanging-while-writing-elements

Comment: @Backs In the general most libraries one can get are not thread safe, unless explicitly noted and even if noted, sometimes hanging:). Is shame, multicore CPUs are here over the decade, but the supports in open source and even commercial products is lacking... Just for the fun, I noticed, that some developers do not consider skills and knowledge of efficient concurrent code development as something that should be noticed as important, helpful, encourage able:).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please note, that the author of the library you are using noted this:

**There is also an issue when writing lots of rows (30,000+) to the Excel file. The OpenXML libraries simply seem to hang when there's too much data to write. I haven't implemented a solution to this problem yet.**

The author noted, that he solved the issue, but hanging could mean, that it is still issue or perhaps it was not meant to be used concurrently...